# find and exec on only filename

Tags: linux, bash, find, exec

I need to find all files older than X days and delete them locally and from my s3 bucket.  The problem is the find command returns me the full path and filename too.  I tried messing with basename and some other things, but could not get it working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For now the 'delete them locally' part is ls instead of rm while I was playing around with it.  For the rm I need the full path.

I need to strip **/home/ec2-user/backups/** out of the s3cmd calls.

```
$ find /home/ec2-user/backups -type f -mtime +3 -exec ls {} \; -exec s3cmd del s3://kisnardonline/{} \;

/home/ec2-user/backups/FILESYSTEM-2016-04-09_00-00.tar.gz
File s3://kisnardonline//home/ec2-user/backups/FILESYSTEM-2016-04-09_00-00.tar.gz deleted
```

Comment: what's wrong with `rm full-path-and-filename`?

Comment: As I mentioned I need the full path for the rm... it is the s3cmd part that is not working with a full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways this can be done. The combination of `find -print0` and `xargs -0` is powerful and safe to work in combination with `sed -z` (using NULL as line delimiter):

```
find /home/ec2-user/backups -type f -mtime +3 -print0 |\
  sed -z 's/^.*\?backups/s3:\//' |\
  xargs -0 -n 1 s3cmd del
```

Since `s3cmd` does not (yet) support deleting multiple files, `xargs` requires `-n 1` to limit execution to one line at a time.

Another way, perhaps simpler, is to pipe `find` through `read` and use bash variable substitution:

```
find /home/ec2-user/backups -type f -mtime +3 |\
  while read file; do s3cmd del ${file#*ups/}; done
```

Comment: the command i need to execute is not rm... it is s3cmd del s3://kisnardonline/{}.  The rm part works fine.

Comment: @KisnardOnline it's now fixed, plus one other option added

Comment: second part worked.. thank you so much!!  find /home/ec2-user/backups -type f -mtime +3 |  while read file; do s3cmd del s3://kisnardonline/${file#*ups/}; done

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try this simple modification:</strike>

`cd /home/ec2-user/backups/; find -type f -mtime +3 -exec ls {} \; -exec s3cmd del s3://kisnardonline/{} \;`

This way every path returned by `find` is relative to `/home/ec2-user/backups/` and starts with `./`. It will work if `s3cmd` and/or s3 server is smart enough to interpret `./` the way it should (i.e. `s3://foo/./bar` equals to `s3://foo/bar` etc.).

> s3cmd does not work with ./

In that case:

```
cd /home/ec2-user/backups/; find -type f -mtime +3 | while read F ; do ls "$F"; F="`echo $F | cut -c 3-`"; s3cmd del "s3://kisnardonline/$F"; done
```

Comment: s3cmd does not work with ./

Comment: I edited my answer to satisfy s3cmd which does not work with ./ .